# Differential GPS (dGPS) in Android

Tags: android, api, gps

My goal is to use multiple android devices to achieve a more accurate GPS position, but from the research I've done around the net, it looks daunting. In order to do the differential calculations, I'd need to be able to access each phone's raw gps data, specifically the pseudorange of each satellite, in real time. Unfortunately, the Android API doesn't have any hooks for this data, only the processed resulting data. I did see, on another forum, that GPSmaster, who hangs out around here, claims to have pulled it off.

So two questions really: First, since I'm a total noob here, is there a way to send users private messages, ie, can I get GPSmaster's attention somehow? Second, does anyone know of a way to get access to the raw GPS output with going way below the API layer and having to recompile the OS?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to message GPSmaster to get his attention -- his reputation is 0, despite the fact that he has a fair amount of activity on this site. Leave the question out there for the full community and whoever knows stuff will answer and vote.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose using @GPSmaster only works if he has already commented on the thread, but here's a test for that anyway.